# Word for lack of understanding at scale?

Tags: single-word-requests

Imagine we're back in the days when the Internet was born. Over the next few years, only a tiny fraction of the population understood how the Internet works.

How would an early adopter succinctly describe the flocks of people who don't have a clue about the Internet?

<s>Note: bonus points if the word refers to an asymmetry of information, whereby one party knows a lot more than everybody else.</s>

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112174/discussion-on-question-by-paul-razvan-berg-word-for-lack-of-understanding-at-sca).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think 'unenlightened' could work here:

> having or showing a lack of necessary knowledge or understanding
> // ... an audience of *unenlightened* laymen.

(source: [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unenlightened))

[Laymen](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/laymen) (or the gender-neutral [laypersons](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/laypersons)) itself is another candidate.

Comment: I think **laymen** would only apply if the speaker were an IT professional specialising in internet technology speaking about people who were not professionals. There were many non-professionals using the internet in its earliest days and these days most internet users are laypeople in that sense as they have no IT qualifications.

Answer (score 3):

**Uninitiated**

The word with the least negative connotation I can think of is "uninitiated". Although "unenlightened" is very similar, and both essentially mean the same thing as "ignorant", both "unenlightened" and "ignorant" are often used in a subject-independent way ("an ignorant/uninformed/unenlightened person") with the implication that the person's lack of understanding is at least partly due to their own unwillingness to learn or adopt new methods.

While these words can be used in a truly neutral tone when they're explicitly linked to a topic ("ignorant/uninformed/unenlightened about message board etiquette", for example), I think they still carry a slight pejorative emphasis compared to "uninitiated", which is always used in a domain-specific way and implies that the person's ignorance is no fault of their own - in this case, the user simply hasn't been "initiated" into the esoteric mysteries of the Internet yet.

Answer (score 2):

Digirati will sometimes call them

## [Hoi Polloi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoi_polloi)

> In English, it has been given a negative connotation to signify deprecation of the working class, commoners, the masses or common people in a derogatory or (more often today) ironic sense.

Here's a recent usage which shows the asymmetry of *hoi polloi*.

> America seems resigned to having a two-tierd workforce, where "knowledge workers" stay home and work via computer while the *hoi polloi* slave away in the trenches.

(from *Fishing, Acupuncture, And Other Newly Virtual Jobs* by John Queenan, Wall Street Journal, 8Aug20, p. C6)

or

## [Unwashed masses](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/unwashed_masses)

> (idiomatic) The collective group of people who are considered to be uneducated, uninformed, or in some other way unqualified for inclusion in the speaker's elite circles.

These terms convey an asymmetry, are both derogatory, and could encompass technology, ability, or knowledge.

Comment: It's a shame that there are only derogatory terms for this.

Comment: I don't think "hoi polloi" works very well - when the Internet came out, the most powerful people in government, business didn't really understand it. Not really sure about government nowadays either.

Comment: Please give some kind of evidence that, *"Digirati will sometimes call them Hoi Polloi"*  It is not enough to simply give a link to a long article without quoting the exact passage. I could not find a single instance of this, either in the article or online. Also, *"unwashed masses **could** encompass technology"*, is no justification for an answer about people who are lacking in technological knowledge. Again, do you have a single actual quote that would support this?

Comment: This question seemed to be looking for a term that **specifically** points to somebody's lack of understanding of new technologies; these terms are far more general.

Comment: @AzorAhai--hehim I visited Carnegie-Mellon Univeristy in the 70s, when ARPANET still had the dew on its transistors. I believe your assertion is essentially incorrect. The only people who *really* knew about it were the government technologists who created the standard and the academics who adopted it. Remember, ARPANET is the *U.S. Defense Department's* Advanced Research Projects Agency Network. How government can you get?

Comment: @chasly-reinstateMonica, I have heard computer science grad students and professor Jon Bentley at Carnegie Mellon University use *unwashed masses* and *hoi polloi*. I remember having to look up the latter. I won't be able to give you the time and date until I finish my BTTF machine.

Comment: @rajah9 I mean politicians and leaders. They are not hoi polloi in any sense of the word, but still did not understand the Internet.

Comment: @chasly-reinstateMonica Adding a recent quote showing *hoi polloi* are the digitial "have nots."

Answer (score 2):

**Technophobe**

> someone who dislikes new technology, especially computers, and is not
> able to use it with confidence
> https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/technophobe

> Technophobia (from Greek τέχνη technē, "art, skill, craft"[1] and
> φόβος phobos, "fear"[2]) is the fear or dislike of advanced technology
> or complex devices, especially computers.
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technophobia

Although this word is not  specifically about the internet, it's close.

---

You ask for asymmetry. The opposite of technophobe is **technophile**.

> 1. a person who is enthusiastic about new technology: "he became an ardent technophile, buying every new gadget on the market" Powered by
>    Oxford Dictionaries

Answer (score 2):

What about "**muggles**"?

Those like Vernon & Petunia Dursley know nothing about the magic world in Harry Potter novels.

Answer (score 1):

What about
**Illiteracy**
e.g. People back then were not as computer-literate as today.

Or:

**ingorance**

Or:

**unaware**

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled upon "arcane" today:

> understood by few; mysterious or secret.

Fits the bill.